# How to print specific key values from a list of dictionaries in Python?

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I am trying to print specific key value from a list of dictionaries in Python, list is as following:

```
employees = [
    {'name': 'Tanya', 'age': 20, 'birthday': '1990-03-10',
        'job': 'Back-end Engineer', 'address': {'city': 'New York', 'country': 'USA'}},
    {'name': 'Tim', 'age': 35, 'birthday': '1985-02-21', 'job': 'Developer', 'address': {'city': 'Sydney', 'country': 'Australia'}}]
```

How can print out specific specific key values and loop through each dictionary? Output should be Name, job and city.

Comment: Since this a trivial task for anybody tangentially familiar with `for` loops and dicts, we expect you to show your attempts and explain what is wrong. Stackerflow cannot give you a tutorial on basic control flow and data structures.

Comment: `for d in employees:
    print('Name: ', d['name'], ', Job: ', d['job'], ', City: ', d['address']['city'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution is following:

```
employees = [
    {'name': 'Tanya', 'age': 20, 'birthday': '1990-03-10',
        'job': 'Back-end Engineer', 'address': {'city': 'New York', 'country': 'USA'}},
    {'name': 'Tim', 'age': 35, 'birthday': '1985-02-21', 'job': 'Developer', 'address': {'city': 'Sydney', 'country': 'Australia'}}]

for employee in employees:
    print(f"{employee['name']}, {employee['job']}, {employee['address']['city']}")
```

Prints

```
Tanya, Back-end Engineer, New York
Tim, Developer, Sydney
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in employees:
    print("name:{0}, job:{1}, city:{2}".format(i['name'],i['job'],i['address']['city']))
```